# Find the number of functions for which $f(1)+f(2)+\ldots+f(n)$ is even

Tags: combinatorics

If $n, m \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, find the number of functions $$f:\{1,2,\ldots, n\} \to \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$$ such that $$f(1)+f(2)+\ldots+f(n)$$ is even.

I literally don't know why the Latex does not visualise correctly, but we have $dom(f)=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $ran(f)\subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. For some reason the set curly brackets do not show.

The number of all total functions is exactly $m ^ n$.

One possible idea for solving would be to subtract from all those for which the condition
$f(1)+f(2)+…+f(n)$ is not true, i.e. the sum is not even, but this does not seem to lead to faster computation.

Therefore, I think we need somehow to actually count the cases in which the sum in question is even.

When is a sum even?

Well, in this case, it's not so easy to say, since the terms being added are not necessarily equal, i.e., the answer is "it depends".

But the general cases in which we get even numbers when adding two numbers: even + even gives even and odd + odd gives even.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The punchline is that it will be even "about half of the time."  In fact, it will be even *exactly* half of the time in several cases, and in those times where it is not exactly half, you can try to figure out why that might be.

Comment: For the case of $m$ even, see [Probability that the sum of $6$ dice rolls is even](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451818/probability-that-the-sum-of-6-dice-rolls-is-even).  The real problem comes when $m$ is odd.  Letting $m=2k+1$.  You can treat that case with markov chains.  Here, you have a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{k}{2k+1}&\frac{k+1}{2k+1}\\\frac{k+1}{2k+1}&\frac{k}{2k+1}\end{bmatrix}$, and you raise that to the $n$'th power.  You can diagonalize this matrix if you like and interpret the results.

Answer (score 3):

Let $e$ and $o$ be the respective numbers of even and odd numbers in $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$, i.e.

- if $m$ is even, $e=o=\frac m2$
- if $m$ is odd, $e=\frac{m-1}2$ and $o=\frac{m+1}2$.

To choose a map $f:\{1,2,\ldots, n\}\to\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ with even sum, you can first choose the even number $2k$ of indices $i\in\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ for which $f(i)$ will be odd, then the set of these $2k$ indices, and finally the value of $f(i)$ for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$.

The number of maps $\{1,2,\ldots, n\} \to \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ with even sum is therefore:
$$\sum_k\binom n{2k}o^{2k}e^{n-2k}=\frac{(e+o)^n+(e-o)^n}2=\begin{cases}\frac{m^n}2&\text{if }m\text{ is even}\\\frac{m^n+(-1)^n}2&\text{if }m\text{ is odd.}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let assume $m$ even. I will prove by induction that there are $\frac{m^n}{2}$ function such that the sum is even

If $n=1$ than there are exactly $\frac{m}{2}$ possible functions (as there are $\frac{m}{2}$ even numbers between $1$ and $m$)

Assume the theorem is true for $n-1$. If
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(i)= 0 \mod(2)
$$
than adding any even number will give you an even number. Similarly for odd functions, so the number of function is
$$
\frac{m^{n-1}}{2} \frac{m}{2} + \left(m^{n-1}-\frac{m^{n-1}}{2}\right) \frac{m}{2}= \frac{m^n}{2}
$$
If $m$ is odd, there are $\frac{m-1}{2}$ even numbers and $\frac{m+1}{2}$ odd numbers between $1$ and $m$. By the same induction argument you can show that the number of even function is given by
$$
\frac{1}{2} (m^n + (-1)^n)
$$